# Is it possible to use recursion on a Stack to obtain the same functionality of a Dictionary

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm working on a programming assignment which requires measuring the nested depth of HTML tags. This is an easy task for a dictionary however we are meant to be using Stacks and ArrayLists for learning purposes. I'm wondering if it would be possible to implement a stack with the same functionality of a Dictionary? What would that implementation look like?

Comment: Why would you want to use a Dictionary here? A Stack, or preferably an ArrayList used as a stack, works great for this without trying to emulate a Dictionary; a Stack is a terrible fit for trying to replicate a Dictionary. (Also, Dictionary is obsolete, as is Stack; you should be using HashMaps and ArrayLists.)

Comment: probably the teacher intends you to maintain a running depth stack as you process line by line, whereas you had thought to store the depth of every node first then process all of it as a second step. does that sound about right?

Comment: In this case you start from the bottom and work your way up, the depth is conditioned on nesting of HTML tags